# MySQL I need a row in table X to return a row in table Y

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables:

The 'players' table that contains all my players:

```
Players | stuff1| stuff2
----------------------------
1       | x1   | y1
2       | x2   | y2
3       | x3   | y3
...     | ... | ...
```

and so on

Then I have my 'bans' table that contains which people are banned:

```
Id | Players
------------
1  | 2
2  | 5
```

Now, with how the contents of 'bans' currently appears it should say that the players occupying index 2 and 5 of the 'player' table are banned.

What I need is a way for me to do something like 'SELECT bans WHERE id=1' and it would return player 2 in 'players' like {2, x2, y2}
 and I have no idea how I would do that.

Help is appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry, my formatting went a bit berserk. Should be readable now!

Comment: Read about and then use `WHERE clase`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The input is 1, which is an ID of the second table (that we'll call banTable). What should the output be?

Comment: If I did for example 'SELECT players WHERE id=1' then it should return {2, x2, y2} (as in the columns of the <player> table)

Comment: Typo, example should be: 'SELECT Players from bans WHERE id=1'

Answer (score 1):

If you need all banned players

```
select p.* from players p, banned b where p.Players = b.Players
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a join:

```
select playersTable.* from banTable
inner join playersTable on banTable.players = playersTable.players
where banTable.id = 1
```

You should really rename your `players` column to something else. The cells of this column don't contain players, but a player ID. I would rename it `player_id`.

Comment: It was just for the sake of this post, the actual columns are like so: 'id, ip, nick, rank, credits, playtime, lastjoin, data'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this::

```
Select Players from Table where ID=? /*2 in this case*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pull players from Players and show who's been banned?

```
SELECT Players.*, CASE WHEN Banned.Players IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE NO END AS [Banned] 
FROM Players
LEFT JOIN Banned ON Players.Players = Banned.Players
```

That would return all players with an indicator of which ones are banned.